# StreamProvider - Issue showing loading spinner (preloader) for loading data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having issues with showing a loading spinner for data outputted via StreamProvider.

Here is the code in it's most basic form. It will need to show 3 states - Loading (data is preloading), Results (if there is data) and No Results (for zero records). Here is some code for a reference:

```
child: StreamProvider<List<Post>>.value(
   value: db.streamPosts(),
   initialData: [],
   child: PostsListView(),
),
```

and the output widget:

```
class PostsListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var posts = Provider.of<List<Post>>(context);
    if (posts == null) {
      return Loading();
    } else if (posts.length == 0) {
      return NoResults();
    } else {
      return DisplyResults();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work as (i believe) posts is never null and i can't use posts.length == 0 for the spinner as this is also used if there are no results in the data.

Thanks

Comment: Any solution for this ?